How can I update a project built on .NET Core SDK 2.1 to SDK 6.0
I have a project built with .NET Core SDK 2.1 which is currently not supported on visual studio and on Azure web service. I compiled the project on my local server and it ran appropriately on the web. I then updated the SDK to .NET Core 6.0 on my local machine and debugged. I keep getting an error as thus:

"resource": "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.317/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.Shared.targets",
"owner": "msCompile",
"code": "NETSDK1080",
"severity": 4,
"message": "A PackageReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is not necessary when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher. If Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web is used, the shared framework will be referenced automatically. Otherwise, the PackageReference should be replaced with a FrameworkReference. [/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/onlineschool-main/bim-edu.csproj]",
"source": "cpp",
"startLineNumber": 111,
"startColumn": 5,
"endLineNumber": 111,
"endColumn": 5

This is line 111 below
<NETSdkWarning Condition="'$(_ShouldRemoveAspNetCoreApp)' == 'true'" 
ResourceName="AspNetCoreUsesFrameworkReference" />

What can I do to ensure this same project runs on SDK 6.0 or higher because I want to host it on my Azure server and Azure doesn't support SDK 2.1 anymore.

Create a different empty project for .net6. Copy all your business references but not .net references, and copy other settings. Drop it into the same folder and build this new project instead of old. Potentially, you might need to fix some namespaces in files. Your problem is that .net6 already includes the library that is referenced in your project

Showing all sort of incompatibility issues after creating a new project and copying all references.

"Not supported" doesn't mean "doesn't work" - you can build .NET Core 2.2 stuff just fine, provided you have the SDK installed. But yes, migrate first.

Post your full .csproj file.

which VS do you use?
